# nlog logging pattern for common behaviour

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, design-patterns, nlog

I use loggin in my operation service class this way

```
   public class   MyServiceImplementation : IServiceInterface
    {
           static Logger log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

           public bool A()
           {
              try
              {
                 log.Trace("Started");                 
                 // Do something A
                 log.Trace("Completed");
                 return true;
              }
              catch( Exception e )
              {
                  log.Error(e);               
              }
              return false;
           }


           public bool B()
           {
              try
              {
                 log.Trace("Started");                 
                 // Do something B
                 log.Trace("Completed");
                 return true;
              }
              catch( Exception e )
              {
                  log.Error(e);
              }
              return false;
           }
    }
```

As result in log i see pretty records as

```
MyServiceImplementation:B   Started
MyServiceImplementation:B   Completed
MyServiceImplementation:A   Started
MyServiceImplementation:A   Completed
```

But at look of code design it's not pretty because of duplication of logic, and i want to write as

```
   public class   MyServiceImplementation : IServiceInterface
    {
           static Logger log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

           private bool CallMethod( Action m )
           {
              try
              {
                 log.Trace("Started");                 
                 m();
                 log.Trace("Completed");
                 return true;
              }
              catch( Exception e )
              {
                  log.Error(e);               
              }
              return false;

           }

           public bool A()
           {
              return CallMethod(()=> { //Do Something A  } )
           }

           public bool A()
           {
              return CallMethod(()=> { //Do Something B  } )
           }


    }
```

but in this case i lost stacktrace in log and information about A or B method is calling losted, i see CallMethod in all cases

```
MyServiceImplementation:CallMethod   Started
MyServiceImplementation:CallMethod   Completed
MyServiceImplementation:CallMethod   Started
MyServiceImplementation:CallMethod   Completed
```

How to take  two goals - pretty logging and pretty code ?

Answer (score 0):

[Decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) is your friend.

i.e.

```
interface Iservice{

bool A()
bool B()

}

class ServiceImpl : Iservice {

bool A(){//do something}

bool B(){//do something}

}

class LoggedServiceImpl : Iservice{

Iservice innerService:

public LoggedServiceImpl(Iservice innerServ){

innerService = innerServ;

}

public bool A(){

trace("A started");
bool res = innerService.A
trace("A ended");
return res
}

public bool B(){

trace("B started");
bool res = innerService.B
trace("B ended");
return res
}

}

Iservice myService = new ServiceImpl();
Iservice myLoggedService = new LoggedServiceImpl(Iservice);
Console.WriteLine(Iservice.A();)
Console.WriteLine(Iservice.B();)
```

Or you can use [AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) library like PostSharp. AOP is perfect for crosscutting concern like logging.

Or you can use DI container interceptions like [Microsoft Unity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178466%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx) that is some kind of rudimentary and limited AOP that doesnt need AOP compiler or post compiler changes in the binary output result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in my solution i'm not writing name of method into log message, it's calculated automatically by nlog from callstack. I write only "Started" and prefix A or B calculated in runtime  In your example -duplication of logic iin both methods A and B.
But i want to write one common Wrapper 
       void Wrap( Action a )
               trace("Started");
              a();
              trace("Completed");
         }
and use it in all methods like
         void A()
         {
                Wrapper(()=> .... );
         }
without loosing callstack and name of method in nlog

Comment: My code is just a example of decorator patter for loggin. I think that if you use nlog with stacktrace in my code you should get something like `LoggedServiceImpl:A   Started`. With decorator pattern you are segregating responsabilities wich is better than having loggin and domain logic in the same class.

Comment: With nlog stacktrace in your example  i will got LoggedServiceImpl:A A Started, it's evaluate method name automatically from stacktrace. You don't need write method name manually. And in this case method A and B identically - all contains same strings log.Trace("Started") and log.Trace("Completed")  and this behavior i want to write in common method.